# save multiplication of two 16bit vars into dd

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I want to save 16Bit*16Bit into dd var. how I can do it? I know that the result are saved to DX:AX, but how I save this to one dd var?

Comment: `mov [var],ax` / `mov [var+2],dx`, or am I missing something here?

Comment: is it that easy? okay tnx!

Answer (score 3):

Since [8086] is a little endian architecture you put the low word at the lowest address and the high word at the next higher (word) address. The correct way to do it is:

```
mov [var],ax
mov [var+2],dx

var dd 0
```

Note that some assemblers might complain because you store a word in a dword variable! An alternative way would be to define *var* of size **word** like:

```
var dw 0,0
```

Comment: tnx, it was really helpful. so basically, when I'm programming in assembly, the size of my vars is just for my computer to know that he need to save this memory for future use and not rewrite on this memory, and thats it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Through the data directives like `db`, `dw`, and others you set aside memory that you plan to use in future operations.